# Complexity of creating decision boundaries for a a logistic regression with polynomial terms?

Tags: logistic, classification, polynomial

I've read in a few places that creating the decision boundaries for a logistic regression with polynomial terms is rather complex and exceeds the complexity of Quadratic Discriminant Analysis. I am wondering where this complexity comes from compared to the regular linear logistic regression model? Where is the complexity in fitting the model or in determining where the boundaries are? Thanks.

Comment: Can you cite & quote the places that say this? I'm not sure what they mean (or whether this claim is true).